# Omniture implementation in Fragments - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, flurry, adobe-analytics

I have an activity which calls the fragment's. I am trying to implement Omniture in Android. I do see documentation for implementing omniture in Activity. But i want to have omniture implementend in my Fragments. Here is the code for Activity. I am little confused to implement in Fragments.

```
@Override
   protected void onStart() {

          super.onStart();
          TrackingHelper.startActivity(this);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {

          super.onStop();
          TrackingHelper.stopActivity();
   }
```

Comment: what does `TrackingHelper` do ?

Comment: you have to start the tracking of lifecycle on onResume and not on onStart.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "**TrackingHelper**" is your own wrapper, anyways you can call this method to track start and end of a fragment in **onAttach()** and in **onDetach()/onDestroy()**. To provide context use **getActivity()** in place of "**this**".